# Azure DevOps yaml find all solution files and execute some tasks foreach solution file found

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to autodiscover all solution files so it will run the following 3 tasks.

For the current solution I need to provide all names of the solution files but the problem is that my company has a monorepository and are still createing new solutions in the folder. Now my co-workers need to add the solutions by hand to the array. The current script is the following:

```yaml
parameters:
  # Specify the solution we need to build
  - name: Solutions
    type: object
  # Continue on error
  - name: ContinueOnError
    type: boolean
    default: true
  # Clean between builds
  - name: Clean
    type: boolean
    default: true

steps:
  - ${{ each solution  in parameters.Solutions }}:
      # Nuget restore the solution
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: "Nuget restore ${{ solution }}"
        inputs:
          command: "restore"
          restoreSolution: "Solutions/${{ solution }}"
          noCache: true
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}

      # Build the solution
      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: "Build ${{ solution }}"
        inputs:
          solution: Solutions/${{ solution }}
          clean: true
          restoreNugetPackages: true
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}

      # Debug variables
      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.Clean }}', 'True')) # Only run this when clean is set to true and the last step is successful
        displayName: "Git clean -xdf"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            git clean -xdf
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}
```

This file works but we need to provide this template with an array of all solutions by hand.

Therefore I was trying to create an autodiscover function that finds all solutions in the repository in one folder and then I need to execute the following 3 tasks to ensure no project is broken with our build validation.

Therefore I created the following:

```yaml
parameters:
  # OPTIONAL
  # Specify the solution we need to build
  - name: SolutionPath
    type: string
    default: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Solutions'
  # The filter for the solution files
  - name: SolutionFilter
    type: string
    default: "*.sln"
  # Continue on error
  - name: ContinueOnError
    type: boolean
    default: true
  # Clean between builds
  - name: Clean
    type: boolean
    default: true

steps:
  # Find all solutions
  - powershell: |
      $path = '${{ parameters.SolutionPath }}'
      $filter = "${{ parameters.SolutionFilter }}"
      $slnFile = @();
      Write-Host "Found solution files:"
      Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter | ForEach-Object {
        $solutionFile = $_.Name
        Write-Host "    $solutionFile"
        $slnFile += $solutionFile
      }
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=slnFile;isOutput=true]$slnFile"
    name: solutions
    displayName: "Find all solutions"

  - ${{ each solution  in variables.solutions.slnFile }}:
      # Nuget restore the solution
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: "Nuget restore ${{ solution }}"
        inputs:
          command: "restore"
          restoreSolution: "Solutions/${{ solution }}"
          noCache: true
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}

      # Build the solution
      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: "Build ${{ solution }}"
        inputs:
          solution: Solutions/${{ solution }}
          clean: true
          restoreNugetPackages: true
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}

      # Debug variables
      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.Clean }}', 'True')) # Only run this when clean is set to true and the last step is successful
        displayName: "Git clean -xdf"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            git clean -xdf
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.ContinueOnError }}
```

The only problem is that I can't figure out how to make this work. Now it just finds all soltuions but it doesn't run the file.

Can anyone help me to figure out how I can make this happen?

Comment: Anything between `${{ }}` is only available during the template expansion phase. At that stage none of the tasks have run an no runtime data is available.

Comment: @jessehouwing so it's imposible to achive what I'm trying to do?

Comment: But the tasks you list here could easily be converted to a single PowerShell snippet that runs the required commands in order. And then it's easy to have PowerShell discover the solution files and loop through them.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks for helping me get out of this loop

Comment: Yes it's impossible. The only trick i can think of it to have 2 pipelines. One that checks out the repo and finds the solutions, then invokes the 2nd workflow and passes in the relative paths to the solution files. But you could also hardcoded these paths, I'm guessing they don't change that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything between ${{ }} is only available during the template expansion phase. At that stage none of the tasks have run an no runtime data is available.

But the tasks you list here could easily be converted to a single PowerShell snippet that runs the required commands in order. And then it's easy to have PowerShell discover the solution files and loop through them.

It's impossible. The only trick i can think of is to have 2 pipelines. One that checks out the repo and finds the solutions, then invokes the 2nd workflow and passes in the relative paths to the solution files. But you could also hardcode these paths, I'm guessing they don't change that often.